# Cant use background-color in css

Tags: css

so i cant use background-color to change color but if im using background property it works and change the color, why cant just use background-color property?

here's the html file

```
<div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button">4</div>
        <div class="button">5</div>
        <div class="button">6</div>
        <div class="button operator">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button">1</div>
        <div class="button">2</div>
        <div class="button">3</div>
        <div class="button operator">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button clear">CE</div>
        <div class="button">0</div>
        <div class="button equals double">=</div>
    </div>
```

here's the css file

```
.button{
flex-basis:25%;

font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2, #ddd);
cursor: pointer;
}

.operator, .equals, .negative{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the funny thing: It's working, just not as you'd expect.

The `background` property always stands *in-front* of the background-color property. When you say the background color of the element is orange, it works perfectly. But the background property is different, and it *covers* the `background-color` of the element. I tried searching for the official term for this, but couldn't find it, so that was my rudimentary explanation. To make this more clear, try setting one of the parameters of the linear gradient to transparent, you'll see that portion of the `background` *reveal* the orange `background-color`. Here's the code that'll make it clearer to you:

```
.button{
    flex-basis:25%;
    
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #ddd);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.operator, .equals, .negative{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

So no, there's no scalable, simple solution for this, all you can do is change the `background` of the other elements to `orange`.

Comment: On the right track, but not completely accurate yet. `background` is a shorthand, that sets the values for multiple of the `background–…` properties in one go. Properties for which no explicit value is given, are set to their defaults. A gradient is technically a background _image_, and a background image always lays on top of a background color. So by _only_ specifying `background-color: orange;`, the background _image_ (the gradient) still applies here.

Comment: See my answer, just overwrite the gradient.

Comment: thank's guys for your answer, now i understand because when im using inspect element the value is orange but there's still background image so the color not change

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite the gradient.

```
.button{
flex-basis:25%;

font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d2d2d2, #ddd);
cursor: pointer;
}

.operator, .equals, .negative{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, orange, orange);
}

<div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button">4</div>
        <div class="button">5</div>
        <div class="button">6</div>
        <div class="button operator">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button">1</div>
        <div class="button">2</div>
        <div class="button">3</div>
        <div class="button operator">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="button clear">CE</div>
        <div class="button">0</div>
        <div class="button equals double">=</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don’t _have to_ overwrite the gradient with a different one though, you just have to “overwrite” that it is set in the first place. That’s why `background: orange` also works fine.